# Laravel - How to Load Laravel on a Custom PHP Script?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a custom PHP script I use for environment restores.  This script is inaccessible via HTTP and can only be executed through SSH with the correct logged in user.  There's a few places in this script where I need the classes and environment variables that I have available for the rest of my Laravel application.

How do I start Laravel and make these other classes and environment variables available if run the script through the command line?

Comment: have you considered using laravel commands?http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands ??

Answer (score 4):

You can use these directives in your script:

```php
require 'Laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';          //the path should match your file path
$app = require_once 'Laravel//bootstrap/app.php';  //the path should match your file path

$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel')
    ->handle(Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());
```

and then you can access Laravel's classes. Dont' know what of them would be available, but i've used this method in Laravel 5 to set some session variables and it worked

Comment: I tried using this, but can't access variables defined in files under `/config` and also custom classes I've created under `/libraries`